# Pandas: Get indices rows of that match group-by value_count

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the row indices for values that meet my search criteria.

Consider this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
                   'item': ['BIOS', 'BIOS', 'Memory', 'Disk', 'BIOS'],
                   'val': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]})
```

I can get the value counts like so:

```
df.value_counts(subset=['group', 'item'])
```

I can generate a new dataframe of results like so:

```
df.groupby('group')['item'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x > 1].reset_index(name='count')
```

But how can I get the *indices* of the rows that return True when checking for my `value_count` condition?

```
# tacking on .index will yield a multi-index result
df.value_counts(subset=['group', 'item']).loc[lambda x: x > 2].index
```

Expected out:

```
[0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` in place of `value_counts`:

```
df.groupby(['group', 'item']).filter(lambda g: len(g)>1).index
```

variant:

```
mask = df.groupby(['group', 'item'])['val'].transform('size').gt(1)
df.index[mask]
```

output:

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 4], dtype='int64')
```

*NB. add `.to_list()` to get a list*

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `transform`

```
df.index[df.groupby(['group', 'item'])['val'].transform('count')>1]
Out[403]: Int64Index([0, 1, 4], dtype='int64')
```